# Single App consuming multiple IoC registries and has conflicts

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, structuremap

I have a single application that talks to separate databases through two individual `UnitOfWork` classes. I am using `StructureMap` to build my classes. Individually, each one builds and runs correctly.

However, once I consume both container registries within my "*Web Application*", I get conflicts.  Both registries reference the same `DbContext` (base) class from their common framework. However, each registry has its own concrete `DbContext` class (that inherits from `DbContext`).

**The problem is...**

1. The moment I consume both registries, last in "wins"...and the wrong
   **CONCRETE** `Dbcontext` class is applied (into the first registry).
2. Multiple instances of `DbContext` are applied to the *Repository*
   references.

**Q:** How do I ensure the right CONCRETE DbContext is applied across my registry?
**Q:** How do I ensure a SINGLE INSTANCE of the DbContext across my registry?

I have tried various methods without success...thanks for the help.

For Example...

**REGISTERY 'ONE' CONTAINS:**

```
For<DbContext>().Use<BBLDataContext>();
For<IUnitOfWork>().Use<BBLUnitOfWork>();

For(typeof(ICompositeRepository<>)).Use(typeof(DbRepository<>)).Ctor<DbContext>().Is<BBLDataContext>();
For(typeof(IRepository<>)).Use(typeof(DbRepository<>)).Ctor<DbContext>().Is<BBLDataContext>();
```

**REGISTERY 'TWO' CONTAINS:**

```
For<DbContext>().Use<WsDataContext>();
For<IUnitOfWork>().Use<WsUnitOfWork>();

For(typeof(ICompositeRepository<>)).Use(typeof(DbRepository<>)).Ctor<DbContext>().Is<WsDataContext>();
For(typeof(IRepository<>)).Use(typeof(DbRepository<>)).Ctor<DbContext>().Is<WsDataContext>();
```

Comment: @Nkosi Could you possibly help with this?

Comment: little tied up at the moment but will definitely check it out later.

Comment: Check this out for starters https://stackoverflow.com/a/16794919/5233410